# How can I match an optional word with RegEx and not use backreferences?

Tags: php, regex

I'm a little confused with the conflicting nature of backreferences and optional strings.

Say I want to find a URL, and optionally have http:// at the front, I'd do `(http:\/\/)...`, right? But would that not create a backreference I could access with \1 or $1 or whatever?

Comment: why? what is relation between escape and backreference

Comment: the round brackets are the one that define backreference, so if you use round brackets the first pair would be always \1 if there is no match then the first one (\1) would be empty.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So you want a [non-capturing subpattern](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.subpatterns.php):

```
(?:http:\/\/)
 ^^
```

Additionally, I suggest you change the delimiter so you don't need to escape all slashes, e.g.:

```
preg_replace('@(?:http://)@', ...)
```

Comment: I've considered changing my delimiter, but Sublime Text 2 highlights the RegEx beautifully, but only if you use `/` as a delimiter.